# Workbox: the danger of self.skipWaiting()

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, workbox

I use Workbox to pre-cache assets required to render the app shell, including a basic version of `index.html`. Workbox assumes that `index.html` is available in cache, otherwise, page navigation fails because I have this registered in my Service Worker:

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');
```

I also have the `self.skipWaiting()` instruction in the install listener:

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

As I understand it, there are 2 `install` listeners now:

- One that's registered by Workbox for pre-caching assets (including index.html)
- One that I registered manually in my Service Worker

Is it possible for `self.skipWaiting()` to succeed while Workbox's install listener fails? This would lead to a problematic state where assets don't get pre-cached but the Service Worker is activated. Is such a scenario possible and should I protect against it?

Comment: Not sure. But: I think you could test this out yourself. From Chrome DevTools block network request to one of the assets pre-caching is trying to cache and see what happens.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I highly recommend "[The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)" as an authoritative source of information about the different stages of a service worker's installation and updating.

To summarize some info from that article, as it applies to your question:

- The service worker first enters the `installing` phase, and however many `install` listeners you've registered, they will all get a chance to execute. As you suggest, Workbox creates its own `install` listener to handle precaching.
- Only if every `install` listener completes without error will the service worker move on to the next stage, which might either be `waiting` (if there is already an open client using the previous version of the service worker) or `activating` (if there are no clients using the previous version of the service worker).
- [`skipWaiting()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase), if you choose to use it, it will bypass the `waiting` stage regardless of whether or not there are any open clients using the previous version of the service worker.
- Calling `skipWaiting()` will not accomplish anything if any of the `install` listeners failed, because the service worker will never leave the `installing` phase. It's basically a no-op.

The one thing that you should be careful about is using `skipWaiting()` when you are also using lazy-loading of versioned, precached assets. As the article warns:

> Caution: `skipWaiting()` means that your new service worker is likely
>   controlling pages that were loaded with an older version. This means
>   some of your page's fetches will have been handled by your old service
>   worker, but your new service worker will be handling subsequent
>   fetches. If this might break things, don't use `skipWaiting()`.

Because lazy-loading precached, versioned assets is a much more common thing to do in 2018, Workbox does not call `skipWaiting()` for you by default. It's up to you to opt-in to using it.

Comment: Excellent! Your comment: `Only if every install listener completes without error will the service worker move on to the next stage` is really helpful. I didn't see it in `The Service Worker Lifecycle` article, so hopefully your answer helps others as well.

Comment: It's kind of the same ground as what's covered in https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#the_first_service_worker: _The install event is the first event a service worker gets, and it only happens once. A promise passed to installEvent.waitUntil() signals the duration and success or failure of your install. A service worker won't receive events like fetch and push until it successfully finishes installing and becomes "active"._