# Workbox: when there is a new service worker, it loads but waits

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I work on Windows Pro 10 and use Workbox 6.x. As a test, in Chrome:

- I load my site
- Create a local app on the desktop
- Start the app
- Press F12 for DevTools
- Check Offline
- Change one of the file and rebuild the site
- Publish the site
- Check off Offline

What I would like is the updated service worker get activated right away, but DevTools says it is waiting.

Documentation says that by default this will be added to the service worker:

```html
  self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
      self.skipWaiting();
    }
```

I check and indeed the code is added,

Why then isn't skipWaiting doing the job ?

Thanks,

Gilles Plante

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [workbox-build](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build) `generateSW` to generate your service worker? Because by default `skipWaiting` is set to false. You can check it [here in the docstring](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ef225a97db24eaf29d9e320f52286408669c7a7e/packages/workbox-build/src/generate-sw.js#L171), and here in the [defaults](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/ef225a97db24eaf29d9e320f52286408669c7a7e/packages/workbox-build/src/options/defaults.js).

If you just want to skip the service worker `waiting` state when you are developing, you can enable [Update on Reload](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#devtools) in Chrome Dev Tools.

[image: Update on Reload]

Also, be aware of the [dangers of skipWaiting()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482680/workbox-the-danger-of-self-skipwaiting).

Comment: Hi, yes I use generateSW to generate the service worker. Thanks for the information.