# workbox generatesw caching

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm struggling with workbox plugin, on each deploy we are having an error like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at vendors.bundle.js?v=c7ac:1:1)
```

Here is my config in webpack:

```
      new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
        cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
        skipWaiting: true,
        clientsClaim: true,
        exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /^(?!.*\.test\.js$).*\.js$/, /\.css$/],
        runtimeCaching: [
          {
            urlPattern: /\.js$/,
            handler: 'NetworkFirst',
          },
        ],
      }),
```

This is serviceWorkerRegistration.ts

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read https://cra.link/PWA

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/),
);

type Config = {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
};

export function register(config?: Config) {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA',
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log('New content is available and will be used when all ' + 'tabs for this page are closed.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (response.status === 404 || (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(registration => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

We are trying to achieve just one thing, don't cache js files, so our users won't need clear cache or update page after an error each time we deploy an update.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is likely due to your usage of `skipWaiting: true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494141/385997 and https://pawll.glitch.me/ for more info.